How do I create an Azure Automation runbook that creates a group access review using MS Graph?
I have a requirement to create Access Reviews for each new group that's created an a specific M365 tenant. Creating these manually is time-consuming, thus I'd like to leverage MS Graph APIs in an Azure Automation runbook.
However I'm being hit with the below error:

{"error":{"code":"","message":"Attempted to perform an unauthorized operation.","innerError":{"date":"2024-07-01T13:54:10","request-id":"fbbb3311-e8c8-45b4-b7fd-d077ce23424c","client-request-id":"fbbb3311-e8c8-45b4-b7fd-d077ce23424c"}}} (Response status code does not indicate success: 403 (Forbidden).)

The runbook triggers from the action group, and group specific details are captured from the webhook into a variable. I'm able to query that group within the runbook using MS graph. So no issue with pulling back data via the graph API.
Here's my Runbook (Note; I will use variables to populate user/group information, but this was stripped back to troubleshoot):
<#
    .DESCRIPTION
        A runbook to create an access review for the given O365 group.

    .NOTES
    
#>

param
(
[Parameter (Mandatory=$false)]
[object] $WebhookData
)

$ErrorActionPreference = 'Stop'

if ($WebhookData){
    # Collect properties of WebhookData.
    $WebhookName    =   $WebhookData.WebhookName
    $WebhookBody    =   $WebhookData.RequestBody
    $WebhookHeaders =   $WebhookData.RequestHeader.Message

    # Webhook name that called This
    Write-Output "This runbook was started from webhook $WebhookName."

    # Convert the WebhookBody into PS object
    $WebhookBody = (ConvertFrom-Json -InputObject $WebhookBody)
    $URI = $WebhookBody.Data.AlertContext.Condition.AllOf.LinkToSearchResultsApi

    $userAssignedMID = "MI-ALL-DEV-AutomationManagedID"
    $userAssignedMIDClientID = "xxxxxxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxxxxxxxxxx" # User Assigned Managed Identity for Automation
    $connectionName = "AzureRunAsConnection"
    $TenantID = "xxxxxxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxxxxxxxxxx"
    $subscriptionID = "xxxxxxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxxxxxxxxxx"
    $resourceGroup = "RG-ALL-DEV-ResourceGroup"

    #Auth token - HTTP Post
    $Url = $env:IDENTITY_ENDPOINT
    $Headers = New-Object "System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary[[String],[String]]"
    $Headers.Add("Metadata", "True")
    $Headers.Add("X-IDENTITY-HEADER", $env:IDENTITY_HEADER) 
    $Body = @{
        'resource'='https://graph.microsoft.com/'
        'client_id'=$userAssignedMIDClientID
    }
    $accessToken = (Invoke-RestMethod $url -Method 'POST' -Headers $Headers -ContentType 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded' -Body $body ).access_token
    $authHeader = @{
        'Authorization' = "Bearer $accessToken"
    }
        
    # Ensure we do not inherit an AzContext in runbook
    Disable-AzContextAutosave -Scope Process
    # Connect to Azure with user-assigned managed identity
    $AzureContext = (Connect-AzAccount -Identity -AccountId $userAssignedMIDClientID).context
    $ConnectionResult = Set-AzContext -SubscriptionName $subscriptionID -DefaultProfile $AzureContext

    #Pull in alert rule kql query search results via the LoganAlytics API.
    $APIdata = Invoke-AzRestMethod -Uri $URI
    
    #Convert Search results content from JSON to PS objects.
    $SearchResults = ConvertFrom-Json $APIdata.content

    #Set variables from the search data.
    $SearchResults = $SearchResults.tables.rows
    $GroupName = $SearchResults[0]
    $GroupID = $SearchResults[1]
    $CreatedBy = $SearchResults[2]

    Write-output "####### New Group Created #########"
    Write-Output "GroupName: $Groupname, Group ID: $GroupID, Created By: $CreatedBy"

    $GroupUrl = 'https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/groups/' + $GroupID + '/owners'
    Write-Output "Group URL is: $GroupUrl"
    #Connect to graph via the rest api. Find and pull back group owner(s).
    $Response = Invoke-RestMethod -Uri $GroupUrl -Method Get -Headers @{'Authorization'= "Bearer $accessToken"}
    $GroupOwner = $response.value.id
    Write-Output "Group owner: $GroupOwner"

    #Review all members of a group with the ID collected from the KQL query now in variable $GroupID.
    #$GroupOwner is the reviewer
    #It recurs monthly and continues indefinitely.
    $ReviewName = "AR-" + $Groupname + "-AllGuests"
    $ScopeQueryFilter = "`$filter=(userType eq 'Guest')"
    $ScopeQuery = '/groups/' + $GroupID + '/transitiveMembers/?' + $ScopeQueryFilter
    Write-Output "Scope Query is: $ScopeQuery"
    $ReviewersQuery = '/Users/' + $GroupOwner
    Write-Output "Reviewer Query is: $ReviewersQuery"
    $FallbackReviewersQuery = '/Groups/' + $GroupOwner
    Write-Output "Fallback Reviewer Query is: $FallbackReviewersQuery"
    
    $Body = '{
        "displayName": "Test Access Review",
        "descriptionForAdmins": "scheduled access review for guest users",
        "descriptionForReviewers": "If you have any questions, contact xxx@xxx.com",
        "scope": {
            "@odata.type": "#microsoft.graph.accessReviewQueryScope",
            "query": "/groups/xxxxxxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxxxxxxxxxx/transitiveMembers",
            "queryType": "MicrosoftGraph"
        },
        "reviewers": [
            {
            "query": "/users/xxxxxxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxxxxxxxxxx",
            "queryType": "MicrosoftGraph"
            }
        ],
        "settings": {
            "mailNotificationsEnabled": true,
            "reminderNotificationsEnabled": true,
            "justificationRequiredOnApproval": true,
            "defaultDecisionEnabled": false,
            "defaultDecision": "None",
            "instanceDurationInDays": 3,
            "recommendationsEnabled": true,
            "recurrence": {
                "pattern": {
                    "type": "absoluteMonthly",
                    "interval": 3
                },
                "range": {
                    "type": "noEnd",
                    "startDate": "2024-06-01T12:00:00.667Z"
                }
            }
        }
    }'
    $Headers = New-Object "System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary[[String],[String]]"
    $Headers.Add("Authorization", "Bearer $accessToken")
    $CreateReview = Invoke-RestMethod -Headers $Headers -Uri "https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/identityGovernance/accessReviews/definitions" -Body $Body -Method POST -ContentType "application/json" 
    Write-Output "Review Result: $CreateReview"

} else {
    Write-Output "No data received"
}`


Any help appreciated.
N.B.
I've edited this problem, as I found my mistake with the original problem (Don't assume you know property values and forget you guessed it).
Authentication is the current issue. The authentication works with the initial requests, but I assume I've not authenticated to the correct graph API Resource for creating an access review.
Is anyone able to help understand what resource I need to authenticate with?
